# Concatenating custom actions with each other

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.2

I read this article http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.4/ScalaActionsComposition about actions composition in Play for Scala but there is nothing valuable in it for me. What I want to do is a real actions composition, something like this:

```
def about = Action { ... }

def changePassword = isAuthenticated { x => isActivated { .... } }

def request = isAuthenticated { x => isActivated { y => hasEnoughFunds { ... } } }
```

Where `isAuthenticated`, `isActivated` and `hasEnoughFunds` are traits (but not necessarily the trais) I create myself. **The idea is concatenating pretty much any custom "actions" with each other, preferably with arbitrary order.**

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: for each check (`isAuthenticated`, `isActivated` and `hasEnoughFunds`), create a trait that you mix in your controller (`AuthenticationCheck`, `ActivationCheck` and `FundsCheck`).

For each trait, define a default behaviour, this is basically a method that takes in a `RequestHeader` and returns a result, for example, in the case of `ActivationCheck`, something like this:

```
def onNotActivated(request: RequestHeader): Result = 
    Results.BadRequest("Not activated")
```

Then the "main" method that you want to concatenate, basically this method will take two arguments, the first (x) in your code above and a function that you want to apply if the check passes, the main method will look something like this:

```
def isActivated(x: XX)(f: => XX => Result)(implicit request: Request[AnyContent]): Result = 
    if(checkIfActivated(x)) f(x) else onNotActivated
```

So, basically, every method you want to concatenate should return a `Result` except the first one (here `isAuthenticated`) that would return an Action. You can also make them all return a `Result` and then wrap the whole concatenation in an `Action`.

Then your concatenation would look something like this:

```
def request = Action { implicit request =>
  isAuthenticated { x =>
    isActivated(x) { y =>
        hasEnoughFunds(y) { z => 
          ...
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: well, what if add more custom actions or would like to mix them in other order or so?

Comment: I updated my answer, you can also make them all return a `Result` and wrap the whole thing in an `Action`. But you can't really shuffle them in any order you want unless you create a super class of all your x, y and z but then again you have to check their types.